# Как работает побитовое или в с++?

Tags: c++, строки, bit

Пытаюсь решить задачу "Удалить или максимизировать" (сайт - Timus Online Judges, номер - 2110)
Вообще не понимаю, как в плюсах работает побитовое или.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std; 
int count(string el) {
    int a = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < el.length(); i++) {
        if (el[i] == '0') { a++; }
    }
    return a;
}
int main()
{
    int a = 0, n, k, max = -999999999, it, sum = 0;
    bool flag = 1;
    cin >> n >> k;
    if (n == k) { cout << 0; return 0; }
    vector <string> dvoichnoe(n);
    vector <int> ch(n), copy(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        cin >> ch[i];
        copy[i] = ch[i];
        if (ch[i] == 0) { dvoichnoe[i] = "0"; flag = 0; }
        if (flag) {
        while (ch[i] / 2 != 0) {
            dvoichnoe[i].append(to_string(ch[i] % 2));
            ch[i] = ch[i] / 2;
        }
        dvoichnoe[i].append("1");
        reverse(dvoichnoe[i].begin(), dvoichnoe[i].end());
        }
        flag = 1;
    }
    copy = ch;
    while (k != 0){
        for (int i = 0; i < dvoichnoe.size(); i++) {
            a = count(dvoichnoe[i]);
            if (a > max) { max = a; it = i; }
        }
        dvoichnoe.erase(dvoichnoe.begin() + it, dvoichnoe.begin() + it + 1);
        copy.erase(copy.begin() + it, copy.begin() + it + 1);
        k--;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < dvoichnoe.size() - 1; i++) {
        sum += stoi(dvoichnoe[i]) | stoi(dvoichnoe[i + 1]);
    }
    cout << sum;
}
```

при входных данных
4 1
98765432 98765432 98765432 1
выдает std::out_of_range в строке, где ищу сумму, при том, что i не выходит за границы массива, и вообще, я не понимаю, как считается побитовое или

Comment: Как и в других языках

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Насколько я понял, вы  пытаетесь в вектор dvoichnoe записать строковые представления двоичного представления чисел (хоть и в кашу превратили эту попытку).  Число 98765432 будет иметь значение   `0101111000110000101001111000` в двоичном виде, и у вас в векторе будет эта строка. А  `stoi("0101111000110000101001111000")`?  пытается вернуть вам `int(101111000110000101001111000)`, а такое значение int не вмещает. Потому и получаете ошибку, связанную с выходом диапазона ячейки памяти.

И, как совет, Вам лучше пересмотреть весь подход решения задачи.

Comment: ясно... а можно ли в с++ увеличить количество памяти под ```int```?

Comment: можно пользоваться другими типами, но это не решение, поскольку это не то, что вы хотите делать, Вы просто получаете результат не имеющий никакого отношения с введенным числом.

Answer (score 4):

числа в компьютере представлены в виде последовательности нулей и единиц, побитовые операции выполняются над каждым битом исходного числа, чисел

например `2 | 5 = 7`, потому что `2` - `010` в двоичной записи, `5` - `101`, `010 | 101 = 111`, что в в переводе в десятичную систему `7`

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  std::cout << (2 | 5) << '\n'; // 7

  return 0;
}
```